# How to filter based on the alias instead of the column name?

Tags: sql, database, informix, sql-like

If i have query like this ::

```
 SELECT a.emp_num, a.emp_num ||'-'|| a.name AS emp_name
 FROM Employees a 
 WHERE emp_name LIKE '' //Error
```

---

How to filter based on `emp_name` instead of `name`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap your query in another `SELECT` and use alias from `emp_name` the first `SELECT` as a field name in it :

```
SELECT x.* 
FROM (SELECT a.emp_num
           , a.emp_num ||'-'|| a.name AS emp_name
      FROM Employees a 
) x
WHERE x.emp_name LIKE ''
```

If you don't want to use a subsidiary outer `SELECT` then you can just pass the whole concatenated string in you `WHERE` clause :

```
SELECT a.emp_num
     , a.emp_num ||'-'|| a.name AS emp_name
FROM Employees a 
WHERE a.emp_num ||'-'|| a.name LIKE ''
```

Comment: @just_name : Have you succeeded?